# Send in/ send in to

Tags: sentence-construction, idioms

Let's say you have just submitted an essay to your teacher via email. By using ***'send in'*** in a sentence, which is kinda *idiomatic* right, could you say:

> I have already **sent in** an essay **to** your email.

Or

> I have already **sent** an essay **in** your email.

Which is appropriate according to the context?

Comment: How about, *"I have already **sent** the essay **to** your email"*?

Comment: "Sent in" means to deliver to a person or institution. I sent in my essay via email to my professor. I sent in (delivered) my tax payment by mail.

Comment: @Lambie, your ''I sent in my essay via email to my professor'' is almost the same as my first sentence, so I think my first sentence is also correct, am I right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You generally use the phrasal verb **[send in](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/send-in-something)** when it is clearly understood where it is going, or it's not necessary to specify:

> I sent in my answer for the competition last week.

If you want to specify where you are sending it to, it's probably better to use the simple verb **send**.

> I have already sent my essay to your email address.

Note that the thing you send is an email: the destination is an email address or an email account.

The correct preposition for a destination is **to**. You might, however, use **in** if you physically place the essay inside something for example:

> I have already put my essay **in** your pigeon-hole.

Comment: I already know the 'send to' thing, but not the 'send in' yet, thx. I really wanted to know this 'send in' thing, AND somehow you answered what I really needed from your first highlighted sentence, so I am asking it as a phrasal verb, and not as an idiom right?

Comment: @JohnArvin: As the dictionary definition that I linked to says, it is a phrasal verb.

Answer (score 3):

Neither example is idiomatic.

The problem with the first is that one doesn't send items **to** emails. One sends them to people or institutions **via** email; or to email addresses. So it would be better to rewrite the first example as:

> I have already sent (in) an essay (to you) via email.

or

> I have already sent an essay to your email address.

The **in** in the first rewrite is optional; the second sounds better without it.

However, in an age where all such work is submitted by email, it's probably not necessary to add **via email** unless it's an issue.

Your second example is also problematic. One doesn't send items **in** other people's emails, as explained.

The best way of phrasing things might be:

> I have already submitted an essay (by email).

Comment: Oh I remeber you Ronald, good thing this question that I have posted is answered here and not cyber-related knowledge or such, because, the hell, I Googled it a while ago and the provided definition are not like these! Anyway, so you mean is whenever you use ''send in'' in this kind of situation, they are always involved with ITEMS right?

Comment: @JohnArvin The **in** is frequently optional but we tend to **send in** applications, answers and the like. Radio/TV presenters generally invite people to **send in** their thoughts/ideas to a programme or channel.